# Active MQ JMS testing using Webservice Protocol

Tags: web-services, loadrunner

Could you provide me the detailed steps on how to perform JMS load testing for Active MQ using loadrunner Webservice PROTOCOL

Does LoadRunner(Webservice PROTOCOL) supports Both Point-to-Point and Publish and subscribe Models?

If yes please let me know the procedure for each of them.

If No,If any other PROTOCOL supports please explain the procedure.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

See product documentation for web services and JMS.  It is documented online in help, production documentation and the documentation online at HP.  You can also use the Java template method with your own code to publish to a JMS queue with the appropriate connection factory settings.

And to your larger question on publish versus subscribe: Yes, JMS can be used to both push and pop messages from a queue with LoadRunner.  As the JMS interface architecturally abstracts whether a queue or point-to-point model is being pushed/pulled from the tool is neutral on the delivery mechanism beyond the JMS interface layer which is being exercised

Comment: Hi James,Thanks for the reply.i have create a script by setting all required fields in Run-time settings and am trying to send a text message to a Queue(TEST_GURU) which already exists,But i am getting the following error:- Error:Failed to send message HI THIS FROM LR to TEST_GURU due to the following exception : javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: TEST_GURU

Comment: Looks like a connection factory issue with your name TEST_GURU, "...exception : javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: TEST_GURU"

Comment: Hi James,here are my runtime settings,

Comment: JNDI initial context factory: -org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
JNDI provider URL:-   tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
JMS connection factory:-  ConnectionFactory
JMS security principal:-  admin
JMS security credentials:-  admin;   
i have placed "activemq-all-5.12.0.jar" in  C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\LoadRunner\jre\lib\ext folder.
Let me know if any thing missing/went wrong here.

Comment: One: I would use a demo service from HP as a control element.  Two: When I did JMS I do it as a Java Virtual User or as Winsock (for MQ where applicable) because of the Dark Magic of the JMS settings on Web Services Virtual user.  Three: It could be something as simple as you having 64 Bit Java and you needing 32 Bit Java.   I start with a control element, known good, shipped in the box, then move out from there in troubleshooting.